# How do I move a text input by user in a textbox, into a textblock in C#?

Tags: c#, xaml, textbox, textblock

menuText is the textblock and commentTextbox is the textbox. I have cleared the textbox when text is inputted into the textbox. How do I make the text input in the textbox to appear in the textblock when the commentButton is clicked?

```
private void commentButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(commentTextbox.Text))
            {

            }
            else
            {
                commentTextbox.Text = string.Empty;
                menuText.Text += commentTextbox.Text;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your question is very obscure. Please see more details

Comment: @jihoh looks you need to swap the position of lines in code

Comment: @Rahul Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are clearing the text box first, so, since `commentTextbox.Text` is an empty string, your last line is effectively doing `menuText.Text += string.Empty;`

You should invert the order of those calls, like that:

```
private void commentButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(commentTextbox.Text) == false)
    {
        menuText.Text += commentTextbox.Text;
        commentTextbox.Text = string.Empty;
    }
}
```